# Создание объекта класса в WindowsForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, классы

Создаю отдельный класс в проекте, условно

```
public class A{
String b;
A(String b){this.b=b;}
}
```

Пытаюсь потом создать объект класса в форме

```
A abc = new A("s");
```

И в результате выходит ошибка, что класс недоступен из-за его уровня защиты, как можно это поправить ?

Comment: Я последний раз использовал C# больше двух лет назад, но по-моему нужно: public A(String b){this.b=b;}

Comment: `public A(String b){this.b=b;}`?

Comment: Чтобы быстро создать конструктор класса наберите `ctor` и нажмите дважды клавишу `Tab`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public A(String b) 
{ 
  this.b = b;
}
```